# Ad Serving Disabled Due To Address Pin Not Verified in Admob Console

Tags: admob

My Admob Account shows message like, "Ad Serving disabled due to address pin not verified". Also, There is no option to verify pin. I have received one address PIN. But, there is no option to verify. Me have not reached the payment threshold and google still disabled my ads

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide for verify the Pin https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772302?hl=it

You will receive the payment when the pin will be verified AND when you will exceed the theshold you have set, that, from what I see, you have set 100 dollars.

If you are not able to verify the pin by the guide, contact the support from the button shown in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find an option to resend a pin too.
The solution was to login to my adsense account https://www.google.com/adsense/ which is linked to admob then go to Payments > Verification check > Resend PIN